# Problem with Update Camera Roll for Version 5.9.0

Tags: expo, camera-roll

"expo": "^49.0.0"
"@react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll": "^5.9.0"

I am facing this error, after change my project expo for running in compileSdkVersion 33 by play store requirement.

Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNCCameraRoll' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary., js engine: hermes ERROR Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if: * Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project. * A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

Can you help me please?

I can not running my project in expo go, I want run it. I received the error RNCCameraRoll.

Comment: Have you tried following the steps in the README file here: https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll and manually add the libraries?